# how to assign a value to a property in the configuration file

Tags: bash, mercurial, tortoisehg

There is a configuration file of repository in `%path_of_repo%\.hg\hgrc`

It has the following configuration:

```
[paths]
default = C:\STORAGE\REPOSITORIES\PROJ_FIRST

[web]
name = The First Project
encoding = utf-8
```

I want change property into conf-file an example. But commands like as:

```
hg config web.name=NewNameOfProject
```

It doesn't work (

What is the correct syntax for a command that edits parameters from the Hg Mercurial console? Thx

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, it is asking how to use the Mercurial command-line modify its configuration files.

As far as I am aware, you have to edit the config files manually.

Its a little hard to prove that you "can't" do something... but looking at documentation etc. there are a few things which seem to corroborate this impression.

From `hg help config`:

> Files ...
>
> Mercurial reads configuration data from several files, if they exist.
> These files do not exist by default and **you will have to create the
> appropriate configuration files yourself**

From `hg config --help`:

> hg config [-u] [NAME]...
>
> show combined config settings from all hgrc files ...
>
> With --edit, **start an editor** on the user-level config file. With --global,
> edit the system-wide config file. With --local, edit the repository-level
> config file.

Furthermore all the other instructions for `hg config` only explain how to get it to display configuration information, not how to modify it.

---

Using TortoiseHG, obviously in its File > Settings GUI it will allow you to modify certain values in the config files; but there is no general capability to modify any arbitrary value.

THG however does have a nice built-in editor for those files which is at least convenient to use.

---

So for `web.name` you would probably use the per-repository `<repo>/.hg/hgrc` file. It should include:

```
...

[web]
name=NewNameOfProject

...
```

for your example.

Comment: No. You have given examples of how to view a value or open a `<repo>/.hg/hgrc`.cd  But, I need a command to change this value. Something like: `hg <typed command><section.property=new_value>` After which execution the property values in the `hgrc` will be changed

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't do that. That's what the answer is saying. I added the last example just to be complete.

Comment: Surely such a possibility exists. May I use short command from bash (somethign combo)?

Comment: I was a little surprised not to find it either. I'm sure you can do it plenty of other ways (bash or whatever) but that wasn't the question.